# How can I find the equation for a "best-fit" surface given the form of the surface equation?

Tags: python, optimization, surface

I have a set of data (x,y,z) in which z is a function of both x and y. I also know that the function is of the form z = (C1)y^3 + (C2)y^2 + (C3)y + (C4)x + (C5). How can I optimize this equation to find values for C1 through C5 so that the equation models the data set the best it can?

Comment: Like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression?

Comment: If you create a matrix A whose columns you fill with y^3, y^2, y, x, 1 you can use the linear regression model of `sklearn` to do the main work. Maybe this helps: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_ols.html to start.